# VueJS State Getter is finding a match but is not returning correct value

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I have a Vuex State where it is storing an Array of `{LevelId, ElemId}` records. I have a getter that is correctly matching the LevelId, but the `ElemId` value that it returns is always `0`, rather than the value for the `ElemId`.

I was initially using `find` but changed that to a `for` loop to try to see why it is doing this. I have a console.log outputting the state immediately before this and it is showing the correct value for `ElemId` but that is not what is being returned. This was working until recently. I am not sure if a recent `npm install` or `npm audit fix` has upset something.

```
const state = {
  LastElemSelIdByLevel: [{
    LevelId: 0 ,
    ElemId: 0 ,
  }],
};

const getters = {
  GetLastElemSelIdByLevel: state => LevelId => {
    // let obj = state.LastElemSelIdByLevel.find(item => item.LevelI == LevelId);
    let obj = 0;
    console.log('Getter for Elem level obj', LevelId, state.LastElemSelIdByLevel);
    for (let i = 0; i < state.LastElemSelIdByLevel.length; i++) {
      if (state.LastElemSelIdByLevel[i].LevelId == LevelId) {
        console.log(
          'Loop found it ',
          i,
          LevelId,
          state.LastElemSelIdByLevel[i].LevelId,
          state.LastElemSelIdByLevel[i].ElemId
        );

        obj = state.LastElemSelIdByLevel[i];

        break;
      }
    }

    if (obj && obj.ElemId > 0 && obj.ElemId) {
      return obj.ElemId;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  }
}
```

From the console.log for `Getter for Elem level obj`
I am seeing eg a LevelId of 11 and a `state.LastElemSelIdByLevel` where the Array Index 3 has `ElemId: 3358` and `LevelId: 11` (In Chrome Console).

However, the second console.log for `Loop found it` shows
3 11 11 0

So it is correctly finding the `LevelId` at Index `3`, and matching the `LevelId` of `11`, but it is returning an `ElemId` of `0` instead of `3358`.

Does anyone know why this might be?

```
My package.json file shows
vue ^2.5.2
vuex ^3.1.0
```

Comment: Can you post the `LastElemSelIdByLevel` value before the 1st `console.log` ?

Comment: Hi Max This is the output `Getter for Elem level obj 45 
(8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]
0: {__ob__: Observer}
1: {__ob__: Observer}
2: {__ob__: Observer}
3:
ElemId: 3358
LevelId: 11
__ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
get ElemId: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set ElemId: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get LevelId: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set LevelId: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
__proto__: Object
4: `

Comment: Sorry about lack of formatting in that. I have tried two spaces etc but it doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thanks to a tip from Linus Borg on the Vue Forum, I have found an answer to the problem. There was a watch in a component that was getting triggered due to some complex inter-play between components, and this was somehow setting the ElemId to 0 mid way through the getter. I put an 'if' into the watch so that it only dispatched the action to update the state if the ElemId was valid, and that seems to have cured it.

Regards

Paul Simon

Comment: Could you post that as a complete answer with code and maybe a link to the Vue forum post?

Comment: Hi It would probably need too much code and I don't think anyone would want to read that much but the fix is as follows - sorry about the lack of formatting - it is a lot easier on the Vue Forum  ```watch:{
      SelectedId: {
          handler(newval,oldVal) {
            if(this.SelectedId > 1)
            {
              this.$store.dispatch('UpdateLastElemSelIdByLevel',{LevelId:this.LevelId,ElemId:this.SelectedId});
            }
          },
          immediate: true
      },
  }```

Comment: Link to Vue Forum is [link](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuejs-state-getter-is-finding-a-match-but-is-not-returning-correct-value/70133/2)